# Can't access .well-known/acme-challenge folder

Tags: plesk, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install an SSL certificate on my shared hosting by Plesk.
It worked before, but the renewal went wrong.
I finally uninstalled the certificate, but when I try to get a new one, I can't access the .well-known/acme-challenge folder.

I tried to put a test file inside but ends up with a 404 error.
If I place the file inside .well-known, I can access it.
If I rename the acme-challenge folder to acme2-challenge, I can access it.

What makes this specific acme-challenge file so protected, and where can I unprotect it?

Answer (score 0):

There may be an Apache module or config that controls the directory. Search a config `acmetool` and the module `md` in the Apache board or in command line with `grep -rinF acme /etc/apache2`.

There are two common modules that manages acme, so to fix it, you may run `sudo a2disconf acmetool` or `sudo a2dismod md`, then regenerate certificate (you may have to wait one hour or one day if you reach the limit of Let's Encrypt).

To avoid a future issue, search for the package that modified the apache config too.